# is this an Admissable heuristic function?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I was wondering,if this can be considered and admissible heuristic function for A* algorithm.

if S is source and a b c are three outgoing edges from S.

h(n) for a = cost to a + cost of minimum outgoing node of a

and similar for b and c.

Comment: No, an admissible heuristic function cannot over estimate the cost of reaching the goal.

Comment: I am kind of not clear about heuristic function. So, my question is,

Comment: I am kind of not clear about heuristic function. lets assume the total cost for best shortest path is 10. so, in my algorithm let us consider, cost to a is 3 and cost to its min child is 4. giving it heuristic cost of 7, following simillarly, heuristic cost for b is 10 but for c is 20 (because cost to c is 10, and cost o its min child is 10). So, can you please tell me is this heuristic function admissible, or it is not admissible because it gave value 20 for c?

Comment: @Gkush the way you describe it, I suspect it is indeed admissible (with an important exception being that, if a is the goal, you shouldn't add the cost of minimum outgoing edge of a). To tell for sure, you really need to define things more clearly (ideally with a picture included) though. For example, what does the ''n'' mean in ''h(n)''? What is ''cost to a''? is it the cost for traversing an edge a? Also, there is no such thing as ''outgoing node of a''. Nodes can't be outgoing, only edges can. And a is an edge, not a node, so there can't be edges going out of a.